# AWS CLI v2: Identity Center: Create User

Tags: amazon-web-services, createuser, aws-iam-identity-center

I try to create a user in AWS Identity Center using create-user (https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/identitystore/create-user.html).

```
aws identitystore create-user \
    --identity-store-id ${IDENTITY_STORE_INSTANCE_ID} \
    --user-name ${USERNAME} \
    --name '{ "FamilyName": "'${LAST_NAME}'", "GivenName": "'${FIRST_NAME}'" }' \
    --display-name "${DISPLAY_NAME}" \
    --emails '[{ "Value": "'${EMAIL}'", "Primary": true }]'
```

The user is successfully created but somehow the password part is missing, i.e. I can't set an option how to create the password. Also no invitation email is send to the user.

So I looked at the process in the portal by checking the API calls and there are two attributes I can't find anywhere in CLI or the API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/IdentityStoreAPIReference/API_CreateUser.html) reference -> `Active` and probably more important `PasswordMode`:

```
{
    "IdentityStoreId": "xxx",
    "UserName": "xxx",
    "UserAttributes": {
        "emails": {
            "ComplexListValue": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "StringValue": "xxx@xxx.de"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "StringValue": "work"
                    },
                    "primary": {
                        "BooleanValue": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "name": {
            "ComplexValue": {
                "givenName": {
                    "StringValue": "xxx"
                },
                "familyName": {
                    "StringValue": "xxx"
                }
            }
        },
        "displayName": {
            "StringValue": "xxx"
        }
    },
    "Active": true,
    "PasswordMode": "EMAIL"
}
```

How can I create then a user including password and invitation using AWS CLI v2?

Comment: You cannot create passwords for new users you can only change that using CLI and AWS IdentityStore

Comment: @PiyushPatil Thanks for your response. So how can I then create a new user with invitation to the user (where the user can then set their password) programmatically? Obviously it works via the portal ("Send an email to this user with password setup instructions.") where they also interact with the API and there are the two attributes and an invitation email is send.

Comment: I think the Console operation is an undocumented API. If you look in CloudTrail, you'll see an event `UpdatePassword` for service `sso-directory.amazonaws.com`, with request parameters `userId` and `passwordMode`. Googling for combinations of these items doesn't turn up anything for me. The Directory Service API has [ResetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/devguide/API_ResetUserPassword.html), but that's definitely not what's being called here.

Comment: My guess is that they assume most "production" organizations will either use an existing Microsoft Active Directory service, or some third-party identity provider, and both of these options have their own way to trigger password resets. But only a member of the AWS SSO or SimpleAD team could answer that for sure.

Comment: As an additional data point, the document [IAM Identity Center information in CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/sso-info-in-cloudtrail.html) has the `UpdatePassword` operation listed as a valid CloudTrail event, but does not show a corresponding public API operation.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. This should solve the issue but unfortunately it doesn't work for me:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/userswithoutpwd.html

"Send email OTP" option in IAM Identity Center console enable OTP emails for users created from API.

The page literally says "Users receive the email OTP when they first attempt to sign in". I wonder what exactly this means since after entering the username it asks me for the password which I have not yet been able to set. Try to reset the password from the AWS Access Portal also didn't work.

Please, try this and tell us if it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).